# Hazard rate with exponential distribution

Tags: survival, exponential-distribution, hazard

Hi I was trying to understand hazard rate and got stuck in the middle. Any suggestions are welcome. Below is the problem.

---

Consider the following distribution for the duration of an unemployment spell $T_{i}$:

$f(t|\theta_{i})=\theta_{i}e^{-\theta_{i}t}$ if $t\geq 0$ and 0 otherwise.

for an individual specific hazard rate $\theta_{i}$

(a) Argue that the random variable $F_{X}(X)\sim U[0,1]$ when $F_{X}$ is a strictly increasing cdf.

(b) Give the cdf of $T_{i}$ and by using (a) show that $T_{i}=-\frac{1}{\theta_{i}}\ln U_{i}$ where $U_{i}\sim U[0,1]$

Now specify individual-specific hazard rate $\theta_{i}=\lambda e^{x_{i}'\beta}$

(c) Demonstrate that you can represent a transformation of $T_{i}$ as a linear regression model with an
error term $e_{i}$ that is independent of $x_{i}$

(d) Derive the c.d.f. of the error term $e_{i}$. Is $E[e_{i}] = 0$? If not, what is the interpretation of the coefficients from a least-squares regression for your model in (c)?

---

Here is my attempt.

(a) $P(F_{X}(X)\leq m)=P(X\leq F_{X}^{-1}(m))=F(F^{-1}(m))=m$ since $F$ is strictly increasing, the inverse function is well-defined. Thus F is uniformly distributed

(b) Clearly, $F(T_{i}|\theta_{i})=1-e^{-\theta_{i}T_{i}}$. This cdf is strictly increasing. By (a), $F(T_{i}|\theta_{i})=1-e^{-\theta_{i}t}=U_{i}$ where $U_{i}\sim U[0,1]$. Taking log on the both sides we have $T_{i}=-\frac{1}{\theta_{i}}\ln U_{i}$ as desired.

I am getting stuck at (c)

If we take log again, we may have

$\ln T_{i}=\ln \theta_{i}+\ln(\ln U_{i})$, but $\ln(\ln U_{i})$ is not defined. How can I proceed from here?
 I don’t get what transformation of $T_{i}$ means

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right

Comment: Use the self-study tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The broad approach is correct but the "$-$" needs to be paired with the $\ln U_i$ (making it positive) and then it's possible to take logs. The sign of the other term resolves itself if you continue by making a suitable substitution.

You end up with an "error term" corresponding to $\ln(-\ln(U_i))$ which has a non-zero mean, just as the question suggested (indeed its mean is the negative of a well-known constant).